# Missing dependency (props) error on useCallback() hook in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner in react and getting missing dependency on `useCallback()` hook.

I tried:

```
const { updatedCartForCheckout } = props;
```

and using

```
updatedCartForCheckout(response.data.data);
```

in the `useCallback()` and setting `updatedCartForCheckout` as dependency, but I am getting a loop.

here is the error message: webpackHotDevClient.js:138 src\components\UI\Navbar.js
Line 55:6:  React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'updatedCartForCheckout'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

**Navbar.js**

```
const getCartInfo = useCallback(() => {
const cartData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartDetails"));

if (cartDataFromStoreFront || cartData) {
  getCart(
    cartDataFromStoreFront
      ? cartDataFromStoreFront.cartId
      : false || cartData.cartId
  )
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data.status === "success") {
        setCartDetails(response.data.data);
        props.updatedCartForCheckout(response.data.data);
        if (response.data.data.items.length < 1) {
          localStorage.removeItem("cartDetails");
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          if (error.response.data) {
            console.log(error.response.data.message);
          }
        }
      }
    });
} }, [cartDataFromStoreFront]);

 useEffect(() => {
window.$("#slide-cart").hide();
setIsAuthenticated(!!tokenFromLocalStorage || !!token);
getCartInfo();
}, [tokenFromLocalStorage, token, getCartInfo]);
```

**app.js**

```
  const [updatedCartForCheckout, setUpdatedCartForCheckout] = useState(null);
    const updatedCartForCheckoutHandler = (updatedCartForCheckout) => {
  setUpdatedCartForCheckout(updatedCartForCheckout);
};
  return (
<>
  <Navbar
    cartDataFromStoreFront={cartData}
    updatedCartForCheckout={updatedCartForCheckoutHandler}
  />
<Route path="/checkout">
          <Checkout updatedCartForCheckout={updatedCartForCheckout} />
        </Route>
```

**checkout.js**

```
const Checkout = (props) => {
  if (props.updatedCartForCheckout) {
cartDetails = props.updatedCartForCheckout.items;
subTotal = props.updatedCartForCheckout.subtotal;
deliveryCharge = props.updatedCartForCheckout.delivery_charge;
tax = props.updatedCartForCheckout.tax;
total = props.updatedCartForCheckout.total;


}
```

Comment: Tried to add just `prop` to `useCallback` dep list? You still got a loop?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito  yes, its looping

Comment: Can you share more code?
I need to see what props you have. Need to check if you have 'updatedCartForCheckout'.

Comment: but from component's father you are changing `updatedCartForCheckout` in some way? It's a function, should never change (I think)...

Comment: @Nitesh i added some more code about the props

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito no,